# Maven rpm plugin secondary artefact not uploaded to repo

Tags: maven, rpm-maven-plugin

I have implemented the maven rpm plugin in the "RPM as Secondary Artifact" style configuration (http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/usage.html)

```
    <execution>
        <id>attach-rpm</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>attached-rpm</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
```

We have distribution management configured in our parent, and this deploys the war to nexus fine.

The rpm is created, but does not get uploaded to nexus however.

I was asked to invoke the rpm plugin in the deploy phase. Could this be why the rpm is not uploaded to nexus? Does it have to be created during package?

Comment: The attached-rpm goal is bound to package phase and it should be create and deployed as well. Can you show a full log output where you see that it is *not* deployed to nexus?

Answer (score 0):

You indeed answered your question. The rpm needs to be created as part of the packaging phase so that is available during the deploy phase. 
Likely what is occurring is that the actual deploy work of pushing out to the repository is occurring before the rpm plugin is being invoked.